# Trying to circumvent NetworkOnMainThreadException on AsyncTask because of ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have the following problem. I am using the DropBox SDK to upload a file to dropbox which works fine. When the file is being uploaded (inside an AsyncTask) a ProgressDialog is being shown with a cancel button, still fine here. What is not working fine is, when the cancel button gets pressed a NetworkOnMainThreadException is being raised. I am new to Android programming but I am suspecting it has something to do with the ProgressDialog which is in the constructor. Since it is not in the "doInBackground" part.

Tried to fix it with implementing the OnDismissListener and doing the abortion onDismiss but still no luck. I am getting the error when "mRequest.abort()" is called.
Thanks in advance for any answers!

So here is my code

```
public class DropBoxUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> implements OnDismissListener {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;

    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;

    private String mErrorMsg;


    public DropBoxUpload(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath, File file) {

        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                mDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setOnDismissListener(this);

        mDialog.show();         
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                    new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                    return 500;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                    publishProgress(bytes);
                }
            });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();          
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mRequest.abort();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the `mRequest` object from the main UI thread as this is what is responsible for the network operation. That is why you get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you call `mRequest.abort()`.

You should modify your code such that you use [`AsyncTask.cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on dialog dismissal and check for `isCancelled` periodically in your `doInBackground` and call `mRequest.abort()` when the task is cancelled.

Comment: thx for your quick reply! so how do check for isCancelled "periodially"? how would I do something like that?

Comment: Usually it is done in a loop. In your case may be you can do it in the `onProgress` method of `ProgressListener` which gets called periodically.

Comment: Rajesh thanks a lot! I just put it in the doInBackground method and it works like a charm. Thanks again! I would have voted your answer up but I have no reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you should call the cancel method to stop your uploading process.

```
ast.cancel(true);
```

where ast is your asynctask object